# The derivative of a function defined by an integral

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb R$. Let $\displaystyle g(t)=\int_0^t f(x)\;dx$, the fundamental theorem of calculus says that $g'(t)=f(t)$. Is this  true for any $t$ or only for $t>0$ ? I mean if $t<0$ should we write $g'(t)=-f(t)$ or it will be the same $g'(t)=f(t)$ even if $t<0$ ?

Comment: It is for all $t\in\Bbb{R}$. The signs are already taken into account in the definition of the symbol $\int_a^b$ (this is first defined for $a\leq b$, but the definition is extended for $a>b$ to mean $\int_a^b:=-\int_b^a$).

Comment: Start with a simple example, e.g. $f(x) = 1$, $g(t) = t$. Is $g'(t) = +f(t)$ or $g'(t) = -f(t)$ for negative $t$?

Comment: You can also think of this way: for any fixed $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $$ g(t) = \int_{a}^{t}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{0}^{a}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$ Since the last term is merely a constant (that does not depend on $t$), you can see that the lower limit really doesn't matter when it comes to finding $g'(t)$.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to figure this question out is to *prove* that it holds for any $t$. So let $t \in \mathbb{R}$, and $h \in \mathbb{R}^*$. One has
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{g(t+h)-g(t)}{h} - f(t)\right| &= \left|\frac{1}{h} \int_t^{t+h} f(x) dx - f(t)\right|\\
& = \left|\frac{1}{h}  \int_t^{t+h} (f(x)-f(t))dx \right|\\
& \leq \frac{1}{|h|} \left|\int_t^{t+h} |f(x)-f(t)| dx \right|\\
& \leq \sup_{x \in [t,t+h]} |f(x)-f(t)|
\end{align*}

Because $f$ is continuous at the point $x=t$, then the RHS tends to $0$ as $h$ tends to $0$, so you get that
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{g(t+h)-g(t)}{h}  = f(t), \quad \quad \text{i.e.} \quad \boxed{g'(t) = f(t)}$$

You can see that this proof works for $t < 0$ as well as for $t \geq 0$.